# Unable to load asset: "/data/user/0/com.example.projectdesign_app/cache/ The asset does not exist or has empty data. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, oop, caching

How to load cache file created within the application, i can upload the image from camera and displayed to the application but i cant use the same picture to anything else

```
class ImagePainterExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImagePainterExample({super.key, required this.image});
  final File? image;

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ImagePainterExampleState createState() => _ImagePainterExampleState(image_1: image);
}

class _ImagePainterExampleState extends State<ImagePainterExample> {
  final _imageKey = GlobalKey<ImagePainterState>();
  final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
   _ImagePainterExampleState({required this.image_1});
   File? image_1;

    

  void saveImage() async {
    final image = await _imageKey.currentState?.exportImage();
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    await Directory('$directory/sample').create(recursive: true);
    final fullPath =
        '$directory/sample/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
    final imgFile = File(fullPath);
    imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(image!);
    await GallerySaver.saveImage(fullPath, toDcim: true);
    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        content: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text("Image Exported successfully.",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => OpenFile.open(fullPath),
              child: Text(
                "Open",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final path = image_1!.uri;
    File imageFile = File.fromUri(path);
    final paths = imageFile.path;      
    final bytes = image_1!.readAsBytesSync();    

    File imgFile = File(image_1!.path);
     imgFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);  


    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Image Painter Example"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save_alt),
            onPressed: saveImage,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ImagePainter.asset(
      imgFile.path,
        key: _imageKey,
        scalable: true,
        initialStrokeWidth: 2,
        initialColor: Colors.green,
        initialPaintMode: PaintMode.line,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the `File? image` is the image i get from uploading image. i can save picture to the gallery using the same file but not to this class for ImagePainter